# How can one ensure that an application starts after Windows startup always at the same time?

Tags: windows, winapi

In other words, Windows starts up, and my application xyz.exe, is started at exactly 5 minutes after boot up. Is this possible to guarantee, within a margin of error of say 10-15 seconds?

Comment: How exactly is exactly given that Windows is not a hard real time OS? Also, is your application a service?

Comment: This may depend on what criteria you use to define booted. After the login prompt is displayed? After a user logs in? After all services and other software has started? Once you determine that, then just start your program and have it wait for some pre-programmed period before doing its thing.

Comment: @Arnold Spence, it's a console app. I need it to run say 5 minutes after user log in. Thing is, I need the log into be automatic, without a user there, and I need that to happen at the same time after a restart as well. Is that possible? Is there a way to have Windows Server 2K8 R2 auto login to a default user? I realize this isn't secure, but it's a test environment. After login, I need the console app to either be run. When do apps in the startup folder get executed, and are they executed at the same time each restart?

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn, as I said in the question, it can be within a small margin of error of 10 to 15 seconds. I suppose I could live with a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be easier just to launch your app at windows startup and then sleep for 5 minutes before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can programtical modify a scedlued task after bootup or login to start your program.